# How do I get objects not currently in a mapping table using fluent linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent

I'm trying to get all the `Catalog` objects that currently aren't mapped to a cart using fluent linq. The mapping table `cart_catalog_mapping` is generated by EF. I use the following domain objects.

Cart (removed comments and extra fields that aren't pertinent to the question

```
public partial class Cart : BaseEntity, ILocalizedEntity
    {

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTime OpeningDateUtc { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTime ClosingDateUtc { get; set; }

        public virtual bool IsReadonly { get; set; }

        public virtual bool IsPreviewMode { get; set; }

        public virtual CustomerRole CustomerType { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Catalog> Catalogs { get; set; }

    }
```

Catalog (again removed comments and extra fields that aren't pertinent to the question)

```
public partial class Catalog : BaseEntity, ILocalizedEntity
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual string Code { get; set; }

        public virtual bool Published { get; set; }

        public virtual int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    }
```

EF5 w/ code first creates the Cart and Catalog table. It also recognizes that the Cart has the list and creates a cart_catalog_mapping table.
I'm trying to get all the rows in the `Catalog` table that don't have a reference in the `cart_catalog_mapping` table. The SQL I'm envisioning is

```
SELECT * FROM Catalog WHERE Catalog.Id NOT IN (SELECT Catalog_Id FROM cart_catalog_mapping)
```

The fluent linq I've tried to use to get these is the following:
public IList GetAllUnassociatedCatalogs() {
        IRepository _catalogRepository;
        IRepository _cartRepository;

```
    var query = from catalog in _catalogRepository.Table
                    from cart in _cartRepository.Table
                    where !cart.Catalogs.Contains(catalog)
                    select catalog;

    return query.ToList();
```

}

Unfortunately the returned IList has no elements. (There are currently no rows in the cart or cart_catalog_mapping tables and 3 rows in the catalog table)

Almost forgot, the mapping tables

```
public partial class CartMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cart>
    {
        public CartMap()
        {
            this.ToTable("Cart");
            this.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            this.Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
            this.Property(c => c.IsOnline).IsRequired();

            this.HasMany(c => c.Catalogs)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(m => m.ToTable("Cart_Catalog_Mapping"));
        }
    }

public partial class CatalogMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Catalog>
    {
        public CatalogMap()
        {
            this.ToTable("Catalog");
            this.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            this.Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
        }

    }
```

Comment: This would be much easier if you add an additional navigation property `Carts` (no change in the database): then you could just say `from catalog in Catalogs where !catalog.Carts.Any() select catalog`. Is there a reason why you don't have that?

Comment: Is Carts:Catalogs a many-to-many or is it a one-to-many?

Comment: This is a one to many relationship in that a Cart can have many catalogs but one catalog can only be associated to a cart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that Cart and Catalog are a many-to-many, from your example. In which case, could you not also put an ICollection of Carts on the Catalog object? If you can do that then all you'd need to do is:

```
var query = catalogRepository.Any(catalog => catalog.Carts.Any());
return query.ToList();
```

Or, if you prefer without using extension methods, you can do it as @hvd suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try converting to LEFT JOIN .. WHERE join is null:

```
var query = from catalog in Catalog.Table
            join cart in CartMap.Table on catalog.Id equals cart.Catalog_Id into map
            from cm in map.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where cm equals null
            select catalog;
```